# How to create a report for below back-propagation neural network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

I am trying understand Artificial Intelligence Neural Network and I am self-learner. Hope anyone would help me in understanding on how to solve this problem

**If this post should be posted here. Please comment instead of degrading the post. Appreciate for this as well.**

I have a question that I am totally confused about how to solve it. I encountered this online but was unable to understand how to solve it. I have added the question below. Hope you can provide some help.

The data set contains 4 observations for 4 input variables (Temp, Pres, Flow, and Process) and an output variable (Rejects). The first column "No" is simply an identifier. The table below reproduces the first 4 observations:

| No | Temp | Pres | Flow | Process | Rejects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 53.39 | 10.52 | 4.82 | 0 | 1.88 |
| 2 | 46.23 | 15.13 | 5.31 | 0 | 2.13 |
| 3 | 42.85 | 18.79 | 3.59 | 0 | 2.66 |
| 4 | 53.09 | 18.33 | 3.67 | 0 | 2.03 |

Train a back-propagation neural network on approximately 80% of the observations, randomly selected. Test the trained network using the remaining 20% observations.

Question:

1. Based on this how to define a fixed neural network with output values and backpropagate an expected output pattern? Here, the output is only one which is the "Rejects" Column
2. What are the error values which is required to be calculated?
3. Does it required to define the hidden layer here? And how can we define the hidden layer?
4. What type of “tool” can be used to create a report for the above inputs and get the expected output? Can you help related to this? I am unsure about one thing as well
5. If not tool could you provide any program to understand this? Preferable tool though.
6. Create a figure that plots the actual and predicted values of the output "Rejects" for the training and test data sets.
7. Does this mean creating a chart something similar to the plot chart we create for the Support Vector Machine? Is that possible to create in the tool where we are using for the above question?
8. How to solve -> Sum of squared errors for the training and test data sets.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: 1) Try using TensorFlow for this. You can specify your layers, which will mostly be a bunch of `Dense` layers. 2) Since your output data is continuous, its a regression task, so you can use things like `MSE RMSE MAPE MAE F1` and so on. 3) Hidden layers are to be defined along with the model creation. 4) Creating inputs and outputs depends a lot on the data, but you would aim to use `scikit-learn` to get the `train_test_split` function at some point of time. 5) Program can be shared once we have your dataset URL. 6) You are talking about `confusion matrix` here. 7) This depends on the model.

Comment: Please see the NOTE in both https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info . Notice that in any SE site (including, but not limited, to SO and the other ones advised in the links) such a question would be closed as "needs focus", regardless if the (seven...!) questions themselves may be on topic or not. Notice also that resource requests (such as your Qs #4 and #5 here) are explicitly off-topic in SO.

Comment: @GautamChettiar Data Set link is the above table I believe and that what I found. Can you train a model based on that?

Comment: @user1413 I'm not able to find the link

Comment: Well i'll try just with that much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the dataset is insanely small. However, this is the way you would approach this kind of dataset, assuming there is much more data.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Flatten

data = {
    'No.': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Temp': [53.39, 46.23, 42.85, 53.09],
    'Pres': [10.52, 15.13, 18.79, 18.33],
    'Process': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'Rejects': [1.88, 2.13, 2.66, 2.03]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop(['No.'], axis=1)
features = df.drop(['Rejects'], axis=1)
labels = df['Rejects']

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu', input_shape=(features.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse','mae','mape'])

model.fit(features, labels, epochs=10)

model.evaluate(features,labels)
```

The results are not good, but that is only due to the quantity of data.

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 316ms/step - loss: 2.4341 - mse: 2.4341 - mae: 1.4419 - mape: 67.6981
```

Comment: I found the rest of the data. https://file.io/D4CFY9cpa7nK. Please use the link. However, I am still confused on how can I plot a figure with actual and predicted values of the output "Rejects" as well as based on updated data sets how can I  Sum of squared errors for the training and test data sets?

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Comment: Since the label is continuous, you wont get a graph of true and false predictions. However you can create a continuous plot of `y_actual` and `y_prediction` and visually compare, and have `rmse` to compare it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm writing a fresh answer because the code for this is tuned to suit the dataset URL that you have provided after the first answer. This time clearly the accuracy is much better due to the quantity of data available.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t')

df = df.drop(['No.'], axis=1)
features = df.drop(['Rejects'], axis=1)
labels = df['Rejects']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.3)


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Flatten


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2000, activation='relu', input_shape=(features.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse','mae','mape'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(history.history['mape'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_mape'])
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Percentage Loss')
plt.legend(['MAPE','Val_MAPE'])
```

And the model training went something like this:

```
Epoch 1/50
7/7 [==============================] - 1s 73ms/step - loss: 10.9066 - mse: 10.9066 - mae: 2.4855 - mape: 111.4739 - val_loss: 5.2550 - val_mse: 5.2550 - val_mae: 2.2529 - val_mape: 99.9000
Epoch 2/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: 4.9923 - mse: 4.9923 - mae: 2.1328 - mape: 95.1877 - val_loss: 3.1912 - val_mse: 3.1912 - val_mae: 1.6590 - val_mape: 74.3683
Epoch 3/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step - loss: 4.0993 - mse: 4.0993 - mae: 1.9074 - mape: 84.9316 - val_loss: 3.0207 - val_mse: 3.0207 - val_mae: 1.6149 - val_mape: 72.3441
Epoch 4/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: 3.5641 - mse: 3.5641 - mae: 1.6932 - mape: 75.8205 - val_loss: 3.0053 - val_mse: 3.0053 - val_mae: 1.5755 - val_mape: 68.8496
Epoch 5/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: 2.9217 - mse: 2.9217 - mae: 1.5616 - mape: 69.8578 - val_loss: 2.4539 - val_mse: 2.4539 - val_mae: 1.4140 - val_mape: 62.5867
Epoch 6/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 2.4518 - mse: 2.4518 - mae: 1.4247 - mape: 63.5009 - val_loss: 2.0144 - val_mse: 2.0144 - val_mae: 1.2820 - val_mape: 56.4856
Epoch 7/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 1.9910 - mse: 1.9910 - mae: 1.2630 - mape: 56.0590 - val_loss: 1.6839 - val_mse: 1.6839 - val_mae: 1.1723 - val_mape: 50.4525
Epoch 8/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 1.1813 - mse: 1.1813 - mae: 0.9188 - mape: 40.1967 - val_loss: 0.7452 - val_mse: 0.7452 - val_mae: 0.7067 - val_mape: 29.3356
Epoch 9/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.8689 - mse: 0.8689 - mae: 0.7326 - mape: 32.4377 - val_loss: 0.3546 - val_mse: 0.3546 - val_mae: 0.4791 - val_mape: 21.1433
Epoch 10/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 1.0251 - mse: 1.0251 - mae: 0.8172 - mape: 36.6930 - val_loss: 0.5519 - val_mse: 0.5519 - val_mae: 0.6279 - val_mape: 28.5509
Epoch 11/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.8735 - mse: 0.8735 - mae: 0.7236 - mape: 32.9642 - val_loss: 1.0568 - val_mse: 1.0568 - val_mae: 0.8415 - val_mape: 36.3284
Epoch 12/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.7933 - mse: 0.7933 - mae: 0.6918 - mape: 30.8646 - val_loss: 0.5851 - val_mse: 0.5851 - val_mae: 0.5987 - val_mape: 25.3339
Epoch 13/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.5194 - mse: 0.5194 - mae: 0.5638 - mape: 24.8541 - val_loss: 0.2628 - val_mse: 0.2628 - val_mae: 0.4087 - val_mape: 17.7300
Epoch 14/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4954 - mse: 0.4954 - mae: 0.5518 - mape: 24.4398 - val_loss: 0.3021 - val_mse: 0.3021 - val_mae: 0.4256 - val_mape: 17.8031
Epoch 15/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4629 - mse: 0.4629 - mae: 0.5339 - mape: 23.4556 - val_loss: 0.2119 - val_mse: 0.2119 - val_mae: 0.3771 - val_mape: 16.3196
Epoch 16/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4563 - mse: 0.4563 - mae: 0.5222 - mape: 23.0115 - val_loss: 0.2919 - val_mse: 0.2919 - val_mae: 0.4207 - val_mape: 17.4477
Epoch 17/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.4153 - mse: 0.4153 - mae: 0.5046 - mape: 22.5874 - val_loss: 0.5661 - val_mse: 0.5661 - val_mae: 0.6011 - val_mape: 25.0547
Epoch 18/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.4056 - mse: 0.4056 - mae: 0.4932 - mape: 21.9288 - val_loss: 0.4406 - val_mse: 0.4406 - val_mae: 0.5216 - val_mape: 21.5496
Epoch 19/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4677 - mse: 0.4677 - mae: 0.5323 - mape: 23.2442 - val_loss: 0.2383 - val_mse: 0.2383 - val_mae: 0.3868 - val_mape: 16.3032
Epoch 20/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step - loss: 0.3991 - mse: 0.3991 - mae: 0.4907 - mape: 21.4421 - val_loss: 0.2270 - val_mse: 0.2270 - val_mae: 0.3835 - val_mape: 16.4031
Epoch 21/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4039 - mse: 0.4039 - mae: 0.5030 - mape: 22.4905 - val_loss: 0.3142 - val_mse: 0.3142 - val_mae: 0.4375 - val_mape: 18.1178
Epoch 22/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3628 - mse: 0.3628 - mae: 0.4799 - mape: 21.5093 - val_loss: 0.3639 - val_mse: 0.3639 - val_mae: 0.4683 - val_mape: 19.1954
Epoch 23/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3455 - mse: 0.3455 - mae: 0.4649 - mape: 20.5179 - val_loss: 0.2378 - val_mse: 0.2378 - val_mae: 0.3864 - val_mape: 16.1129
Epoch 24/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3276 - mse: 0.3276 - mae: 0.4523 - mape: 19.8604 - val_loss: 0.2182 - val_mse: 0.2182 - val_mae: 0.3768 - val_mape: 15.9712
Epoch 25/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3175 - mse: 0.3175 - mae: 0.4485 - mape: 20.0487 - val_loss: 0.3083 - val_mse: 0.3083 - val_mae: 0.4336 - val_mape: 17.9253
Epoch 26/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3289 - mse: 0.3289 - mae: 0.4514 - mape: 20.1608 - val_loss: 0.3361 - val_mse: 0.3361 - val_mae: 0.4495 - val_mape: 18.4325
Epoch 27/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3233 - mse: 0.3233 - mae: 0.4471 - mape: 19.8604 - val_loss: 0.2534 - val_mse: 0.2534 - val_mae: 0.4036 - val_mape: 17.1102
Epoch 28/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3226 - mse: 0.3226 - mae: 0.4441 - mape: 19.3694 - val_loss: 0.2483 - val_mse: 0.2483 - val_mae: 0.3982 - val_mape: 16.7979
Epoch 29/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3188 - mse: 0.3188 - mae: 0.4439 - mape: 19.5424 - val_loss: 0.2392 - val_mse: 0.2392 - val_mae: 0.3908 - val_mape: 16.4567
Epoch 30/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3109 - mse: 0.3109 - mae: 0.4457 - mape: 19.7457 - val_loss: 0.2292 - val_mse: 0.2292 - val_mae: 0.3859 - val_mape: 16.4228
Epoch 31/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2999 - mse: 0.2999 - mae: 0.4337 - mape: 19.1884 - val_loss: 0.2527 - val_mse: 0.2527 - val_mae: 0.3966 - val_mape: 16.4614
Epoch 32/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3091 - mse: 0.3091 - mae: 0.4313 - mape: 18.9708 - val_loss: 0.2601 - val_mse: 0.2601 - val_mae: 0.4023 - val_mape: 16.6517
Epoch 33/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2974 - mse: 0.2974 - mae: 0.4363 - mape: 19.4105 - val_loss: 0.2839 - val_mse: 0.2839 - val_mae: 0.4175 - val_mape: 17.1926
Epoch 34/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2786 - mse: 0.2786 - mae: 0.4177 - mape: 18.4687 - val_loss: 0.1865 - val_mse: 0.1865 - val_mae: 0.3689 - val_mape: 16.4617
Epoch 35/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3164 - mse: 0.3164 - mae: 0.4466 - mape: 19.8367 - val_loss: 0.3088 - val_mse: 0.3088 - val_mae: 0.4362 - val_mape: 18.0655
Epoch 36/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3097 - mse: 0.3097 - mae: 0.4339 - mape: 19.2173 - val_loss: 0.2615 - val_mse: 0.2615 - val_mae: 0.4002 - val_mape: 16.4560
Epoch 37/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2861 - mse: 0.2861 - mae: 0.4249 - mape: 18.7808 - val_loss: 0.2223 - val_mse: 0.2223 - val_mae: 0.3794 - val_mape: 16.0339
Epoch 38/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2967 - mse: 0.2967 - mae: 0.4334 - mape: 19.1338 - val_loss: 0.1935 - val_mse: 0.1935 - val_mae: 0.3679 - val_mape: 16.0777
Epoch 39/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.3012 - mse: 0.3012 - mae: 0.4307 - mape: 18.8958 - val_loss: 0.2027 - val_mse: 0.2027 - val_mae: 0.3718 - val_mape: 16.1167
Epoch 40/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.2926 - mse: 0.2926 - mae: 0.4204 - mape: 18.5881 - val_loss: 0.2174 - val_mse: 0.2174 - val_mae: 0.3810 - val_mape: 16.5433
Epoch 41/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2947 - mse: 0.2947 - mae: 0.4214 - mape: 18.9445 - val_loss: 0.3573 - val_mse: 0.3573 - val_mae: 0.4648 - val_mape: 19.0649
Epoch 42/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.3088 - mse: 0.3088 - mae: 0.4332 - mape: 19.3028 - val_loss: 0.2762 - val_mse: 0.2762 - val_mae: 0.4090 - val_mape: 16.7506
Epoch 43/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.2898 - mse: 0.2898 - mae: 0.4235 - mape: 18.5388 - val_loss: 0.2007 - val_mse: 0.2007 - val_mae: 0.3747 - val_mape: 16.6556
Epoch 44/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2835 - mse: 0.2835 - mae: 0.4168 - mape: 18.4563 - val_loss: 0.2329 - val_mse: 0.2329 - val_mae: 0.3871 - val_mape: 16.3445
Epoch 45/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.2685 - mse: 0.2685 - mae: 0.4109 - mape: 18.3725 - val_loss: 0.2807 - val_mse: 0.2807 - val_mae: 0.4141 - val_mape: 16.9569
Epoch 46/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.2783 - mse: 0.2783 - mae: 0.4205 - mape: 18.4501 - val_loss: 0.2055 - val_mse: 0.2055 - val_mae: 0.3726 - val_mape: 16.0784
Epoch 47/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step - loss: 0.2712 - mse: 0.2712 - mae: 0.4225 - mape: 18.8953 - val_loss: 0.2424 - val_mse: 0.2424 - val_mae: 0.3906 - val_mape: 16.3056
Epoch 48/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2623 - mse: 0.2623 - mae: 0.4113 - mape: 18.3200 - val_loss: 0.2274 - val_mse: 0.2274 - val_mae: 0.3821 - val_mape: 16.0680
Epoch 49/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 0.2629 - mse: 0.2629 - mae: 0.4026 - mape: 17.8561 - val_loss: 0.2516 - val_mse: 0.2516 - val_mae: 0.3948 - val_mape: 16.2785
Epoch 50/50
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: 0.2641 - mse: 0.2641 - mae: 0.3969 - mape: 17.4429 - val_loss: 0.2531 - val_mse: 0.2531 - val_mae: 0.4031 - val_mape: 17.0205
```